# Design pattern for inheriting across modules

Tags: python, inheritance, design-patterns, module

I have a `BaseClass` object with two `ChildClass` objects inheriting from it. Each of these is a significant bit of code (>1000 lines) and they each have their own module.
So the structure is as follows:

**Module 1 with BaseClass**

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class BaseClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
```

**Module 2 with ChildClass 1**

```
from module1 import BaseClass

class ChildClass1(BaseClass):
```

**Module 3 with ChildClass 2**

```
from module1 import BaseClass

class ChildClass2(BaseClass):
```

At the moment I am using (I think) a Factory Design Pattern, where I have a function in a separate module controlling which ChildClass is called:

**Module 4 with Class Controller**

```
from module2 import ChildClass1
from module3 import ChildClass2

def controller():
    if condition:
        return ChildClass1()
    else:
        return ChildClass2()
```

I can't put this function in Module 1 because I will end up with circular  imports so currently it is sitting in its own module.

A previous version of the code had the controller as a `staticmethod` to the `BaseClass` in Module 1 with the `import ChildClass` statements within the `staticmethod`, but I didn't like that pattern so I changed it to the current structure.

My question is - Is there a better design pattern that I can use without having to put everything in the same module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I decided to make the class controller a class of its own, so Module 4 looks something like the following:

```
from module2 import ChildClass1
from module3 import ChildClass2

class Controller:

    def __init__(self, *args):
        if condition:
            self.strategy = ChildClass1()
        else:
            self.strategy = ChildClass2()
```

Then I just need to initialize the controller and call methods on the strategy object.
I believe this is an example of the [Strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).